# Flex box layout

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am developing a layout with bootstrap and some flex containers and can't seem to find out why my box would always grow larger than its container. I created a fiddle to illustrate the problem:
[example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q0oeapr7/27/)
.

The html part looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid overflow-hidden">
  <div class="row flex-nowrap">
    <div class="col const-width">
      const
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="bigcontent">
        some very very very very very very very very very very very big content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col const-width">
      const
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the css is the following:

```
.const-width {
  max-width: 100px !important;
  min-width: 100px !important;
}

.bigcontent {
  background: #aaaaaa;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

As you can see, I have two constant width boxes on the sides and a flexible box that should take up the rest of the space between the other two. If the content of the flexible-width box grows too big, the rightmost box get's pushed off-screen. What I want instead is, that the content of the flexible-width box gets scrollable and everything remains on-screen.

I tried this by wrapping the content in another div, but couldn't get it to work.

Any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like this?

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-x:auto!important;
}

.const-width {
  max-width: 100px !important;
  min-width: 100px !important;
}

.bigcontent {
  background: #aaaaaa;
  min-width: 500px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  
}
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
      
<div class="container overflow-hidden">
  <div class="row flex-nowrap">
    <div class="col const-width">
      const
    </div>
    <div class="col ">
      
        <div class="bigcontent">
        some very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very big content
       
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col const-width">
      const
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I delete scroll div and apply overflow-x to **.col** class auto with **!important** rule